# How to validate values in a YAML configuration file while loading it?

Tags: java, yaml, snakeyaml

Is there a way to validate values in a YAML file while loading it in the code. The requirement is I have some elements in the YAML file which must have values. If the validation fails, then YAML should not be loaded.

I'm using snakeyaml library and heard there is a way to do this via Representer.

Code I'm currently using to load the YAML,

```
Reader in = new InputStreamReader(Files.newInputStream(file), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
Yaml yaml = new Yaml();
yaml.setBeanAccess(BeanAccess.FIELD);
return yaml.loadAs(in, School.class);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you can have any value in a YAML file, you should load the file in a function, test the values and raise an error if the values are not what you want. Return the loaded data if they are.

This may have side-effects if your YAML has tags that create arbitrary objects, but checking during loading will not prevent that, as such object might have been created before you come to the value you want to check.

If you do have tags in your YAML and that is a real problem, then you would have to make a `safe_load`-er for the YAML file that can handle the tags (by creating normal mapping objects), then check the values and reload with full tag support.